# How to fix ' name "xxx" is not defined

Tags: python, defined, replit

In my program, I'm trying to run a "def command" in a conditional statement. An error pops up saying name 'command' is not defined.

I tried to rewrite the code and tried to reload the repl.it server many times.

```
def main():
   inputmain = input("...")
   if inputmain == "Yes" or "yes" or "y" or "Y":
     command()
  elif inputmain == "No" or "no" or "n" or "N":
     print("Ok.")
  else:
     print("Error")
main()
def command():
 ...
 ...
command()
```

I expect the output of "y" to be the program command() but it's the error above.

Comment: You've defined command() after you used it, so define it at the top

Comment: Yes, but then command() will be first. Or in this case (if it said print("......")) then it would print ...... then do everything else.

Comment: Defining `command` won't run it. You define it at the start so you can use it later

Comment: But when I run it with command at the top, it does command first.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason you shouldn't be calling command after you define it

Comment: You don't put `command()` at the top, just the `define command()`

Comment: As a side note, you need `if inputmain in ("Yes", "yes", "y", "Y"):`  and the same for the "no" version instead of what you have written. Your code does not work as you intend.

Comment: So do i write    define command():     or     def command():

Comment: @DhruvilMehta Just `def command():`

Comment: with the code for def command(): underneath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments were growing long. Here is an amended version of your code. As you can see, I am not calling `command()` anywhere except in the `main()` function.

The `command()` function does *not* need to be defined before `main()` is defined. It just needs to be defined before `main()` is *executed* because `main()` may potentially call on it.

```
def main():
   inputmain = input("...")
   if inputmain in ("Yes", "yes", "y", "Y"):
        command()
   elif inputmain in ("No", "no", "n", "N"):
        print("Ok.")
   else:
        print("Error")

def command():
    print(1)

main()
```

Comment: @DhruvilMehta I understand you are new. It is typical for the person posing the question to upvote/downvote the responses accordingly and/or select a response as the accepted answer. No need to comment unless the response needs editing or clarification. I'm happy to have helped.